# How to refer layouts and other resources from aar into application?

Tags: android, xml, layout, resources, aar

If I want to use layouts from aar, how do i fill the include parameters in xml? What about other resources?

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/titlebar"
    layout="@layout/title_bar" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/layoutChat"
    layout="???"/>
```